# What is the growth rate of a function $f(n)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty (1-1/n)^{i(i-1)/2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I want to find the growth rate of the function $$f(n)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty (1-1/n)^{i(i-1)/2}$$

Since $(1+x)^k\approx 1+kx$ for $|x|\ll1$, I modified $f(n)$ to
$$ f(n) \approx \sum_{i=1}^\infty \left[1-\frac{i(i-1)}{2n}\right] $$
for $n$ large, but this diverges. How can I find the correct growth rate? I strongly conjecture it will be $O(\sqrt n)$.

Comment: The question is about the asymptotic behavior of the theta function $\sum_{i \geq 1} a^{i (i - 1)}$ near $a = 1$. Using the fact that this sum is asymptotically equivalent to the corresponding integral, we get $f(n) \sim \sqrt {\pi n / 2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the function $g_n(x)=(1-1/n)^{x(x-1)/2}$ is monotone decreasing for $x\ge1$, we have
$$
\int_1^\infty g_n(x)dx\le f(n)\le \int_1^\infty g_n(x)dx+1-1/n.
$$
(Hint: Compare the integral with its Riemann sums, where the integer points are takes as nodes.) Now
$$
 \int_1^\infty g_n(x)dx=\int_1^\infty e^{\ln(1-1/n)x(x-1)/2}dx
=\frac1{\sqrt{-\ln(1-1/n)}}
\int_1^\infty e^{-y^2/2+y/(2\sqrt{-\ln(1-1/n)})}dy.
$$ 
The last integral is bounded above and below by positive constants independent of  $n$, and it remains to note that $-\ln(1-1/n)\approx 1/n$ and hence
$$\frac1{\sqrt{-\ln(1-1/n)}}\approx\sqrt n$$ for large $n$. Thus, your guess is correct.

Comment: How is the last integral calculated? Is that integration by parts?

Comment: We need not calculate it, just estimate:$e^{-y^2/2}\le e^{-y^2/2+y/(2\sqrt{-\ln(1-1/n)})}\le e^{-y^2/2+y/2}$, and a similar inequality holds for the integrals of these functions.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the last equal sign (i.e., the second integral).

Comment: You make the change of variables $x=y/\sqrt{-\ln(1-1/n)}$.

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanations!

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, you might wish to mark the answer as accepted.